# RubyMine stopped recognizing html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

my rubymine stopped recognizing html.erb files :s
You can see how it looks here:
http://pasteboard.co/1D5oWZGB.png

If your suggestion, its a uninstall, please tel me how to do it on Ubuntu :)
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on what you're showing us with the screenshot RubyMine's built in file type system is no longer seeing the *.erb files as RHTML or Ruby files anymore.

Please verify that your file mappings are correct by going into the settings menu (File -> Settings or Ctrl + Alt + S) and checking the listed file mappings by going into Editor -> File Types -> RHTML.

It should look something like this:
[image: Rubymine File Types]

If *.erb is not listed there try adding it again and it should re-enable code highlighting etc.

Comment: any reason you can think of why a recognized .erb file formats like simple plain text, without any colors, etc? What I'm seeing cannot be considered even remotely useful, but I'm unable to get meaningful display of any .erb file in an editor, no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes across this, I have found the correct solution to the problem. ivopatty's answer doesn't quite address the question.

According to pasteboard, we see only friendlist.html.erb file is not being recognized, there's no problem with other *.erb files.

To solve this problem, search for registered pattern in text file type (you can access it by pressing Ctrl + Alt + S) and you'll see that file listed there. If it's not there, search throughout the other file types. Then you remove the file from the list and you'll solve this problem.